# Java WebView or TextFlow: only display substring that fits the space

Tags: javafx, webview

I am trying to make a `TableColumn` that displays Message title and message body. It should have behavior similar to Gmail. That is display Title (bold), and Message body (regular) in one line.

**Message title** Message body. Both strings are short - can display all
**Message title** Now Message body is long. Only display the beginning of ...
**Now message title is quite long too. Only message title fits this time...**

Problem
`Label`, `Text`: cannot display two styles.
HBox with two `Text` : display **...ge Ti...** ..ssage Body... (desired: **Message Title** Me..)
`TextFlow`, `WebView`: cannot force `setWrap(false)`. JavaFX displays ugly multiline text.
Compute subString based on ColumnWidth using code below. Fires recalculation of graphics of all cells on each column resize. Possible but feels like reinventing a wheel for a low level language.

Is there a build in way to display the beginning of a string with two styles in one line?

```
private Double getSubstringLength(String preparedTitle, String headerStyle){

    Text disposable = new Text();
    disposable.setText(preparedTitle);
    disposable.setStyle(headerStyle);

    return disposable.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
}
```

Comment: No time to test, but use an `HBox` with two `Label`s; set `HBox.hgrow` to `ALWAYS` for the first label, and `NEVER` for the second label: set the `minWidth` of the second label to zero (or something small if you want to be able to always see the elipsis).

Comment: Will test and post the result. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried James's suggestion and did not give the desired outcome.  It always prioritizes eliding the first label.  The grow priority only applies to additional space after the preferred size of all controls is filled in, so I don't think it is quite that straightforward.  You may need to create a custom layout pane for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom layout pane.

[image: sample custom pane]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MailViewSample extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<Message> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Message("Jacob", "Message title 1", "Message body. Both strings are short - can display all"),
            new Message("Isabella", "Message title 2", "Now Message body is long. Only display the beginning of this longer body"),
            new Message("Ethan", "Now message title is quite long too. Only message title fits this time no body seen", "Message body not seen")
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class MessagePane extends Pane {
        private static final double SPACING = 10;

        private final Label title;
        private final Label body;

        public MessagePane(Label title, Label body) {
            super(title, body);

            this.title = title;
            this.body = body;
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            double width = getWidth();
            double height = getHeight();
            double baselineOffset = Math.max(title.getBaselineOffset(), body.getBaselineOffset());

            if (title.prefWidth(-1) + SPACING + body.minWidth(-1) > width) {
                layoutInArea(title, 0, 0, width, height, baselineOffset, HPos.LEFT, VPos.BASELINE);
                layoutInArea(body, 0, 0, 0, 0, baselineOffset, HPos.LEFT, VPos.BASELINE);
            } else {
                double titleWidth = title.prefWidth(-1);
                layoutInArea(title, 0, 0, titleWidth, height, baselineOffset, HPos.LEFT, VPos.BASELINE);
                double bodyWidth = Math.max(0, Math.min(width - (titleWidth + SPACING), body.prefWidth(-1)));
                layoutInArea(body, titleWidth + SPACING, 0, bodyWidth, height, baselineOffset, HPos.LEFT, VPos.BASELINE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<Message> table = new TableView<>(data);
        table.setPrefHeight(150);

        TableColumn<Message, String> senderCol = new TableColumn<>("Sender");
        senderCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("sender"));
        table.getColumns().add(senderCol);

        TableColumn<Message, Message> messageCol = new TableColumn<>("Message");
        messageCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(param.getValue()));
        messageCol.setCellFactory(param -> new TableCell<Message, Message>() {
            Label title = new Label();
            Label body = new Label();
            MessagePane messagePane = new MessagePane(title, body);

            {
                title.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Message item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                title.textProperty().unbind();
                body.textProperty().unbind();

                if (empty || item == null) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    title.setText(item.getTitle());
                    body.setText(item.getBody());
                    title.textProperty().bind(item.titleProperty());
                    body.textProperty().bind(item.bodyProperty());

                    setGraphic(messagePane);
                }
            }
        });
        messageCol.setPrefWidth(520);

        table.getColumns().add(messageCol);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(table));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Message {
        private final SimpleStringProperty sender;
        private final SimpleStringProperty title;
        private final SimpleStringProperty body;

        private Message(String sender, String title, String body) {
            this.sender = new SimpleStringProperty(sender);
            this.title = new SimpleStringProperty(title);
            this.body = new SimpleStringProperty(body);
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty senderProperty() {
            return sender;
        }

        public String getSender() {
            return sender.get();
        }

        public void setSender(String sender) {
            this.sender.set(sender);
        }
        public SimpleStringProperty titleProperty() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title.get();
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title.set(title);
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty bodyProperty() {
            return body;
        }

        public String getBody() {
            return body.get();
        }

        public void setBody(String body) {
            this.body.set(body);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Concise and works as expected, thank you! To those interested how does it work: (1) `TableColumn<Message, Message> messageCol` (don't limit yourself to `TableColumn<Message, Integer>` or `TableColumn<Message, String>`) (2) `class MessagePane extends Pane {/*...*/}` specifies the layout.